# Travis-ci can not build github commit made by other github repository contributors

Tags: java, git, github, travis-ci

I have made an integration between Travis and my github account and it works fine.

However when any of my project contributors commit to the master branch of the repository, Travis fail to build the changes with this line of error only:

```
An error occurred while generating the build script.
```

I tried to find any access permission or something which is related to this issue but I could not find any. do you have any suggestion about this ?

Comment: Do your pushed commits run fine with Travis? Do the contributors modified the file `.travis.yml` and is this file part of their commits?

Comment: @fedepad as I mentioned in the question, I have no problem committing and building. there's only one contributor that has this problem. I checked and saw that his commit was ok but the build was failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a few things that could cause this:

1. Wrong permissions for your contributors (but you excluded this case!)
2. Your contributors pushed an erroneous (wrongly formatted, etc.) `.travis.yml` file as part of their commits (don't know if they do; just if they do, it might trigger the error): in this case would be a good idea to validate the file in http://lint.travis-ci.org/ before committing and pushing
3. Some people thought in their case was probably associated to massive DNS outages (might be the case or not): https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6441